# Rails_admin Dropdown menu with has_many, belongs_to models relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-admin

Im building a rails admin dropdown with various different models in my app. The two models I want to link are Student and Company. Student belongs_to Company and Company has_many Student's.
The code is as follows:

```
RailsAdmin.confing do |config|
...
config.model 'Student' do
   edit do
       ...
       various fields
       ...
       field connection_with_company, :enum do     
          connection_with_company
       ...
```

I already have created a method in the Student model returning the values I need but rails admin does not read the methods I make in the model.
The idea is when adding a new student, list the available companies. I have searched and tried almost everything. I already tried custom field and virtual field, although there is a possibility I may have done it wrong.
Any help will be much appreciated!!
Thank you!

**Update**

Tried this but it does not appear on the edit section

```js
$('#academy.id').parent().hide() academies = $('#academy.id').html() 
$('#company_profiles.company_id').change -> 
  companies = $('#company_profiles.company_id :selected').text()
  escaped_companies = companies.replace(/([ #;&,.+*~\':"!^$[\]()=>|\/@])/g, '\\$1') 
  options = $(academies).filter("optgroup[label='#{companies}']").html()
  if options $('#academy.id').html(options)
    $('#academy.id').parent().show() 
  else 
    $('#academy.id').empty() $('#academy.id').parent().hide()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can’t configure rails admin to have one field values depend on the value of another field, at least not without first saving the object. 
You’d have to build a new field that combines both. 
Which path do you want? The chose a student save the object and then show the companies field with the filtered values?
Or the sprinkle javascript magic on a brand new field that combines two?

Can you try adding this file?

```
app/assets/javascripts/rails_admin/custom/ui.js

//= require_tree .
//= require 'rails_admin/custom/yourfile.js'
```

Comment: The information i want to get form Student, comes from Company and a couple of other models. If there is a javascript "magic" please do share ahaha. I was thinking that i needed to already have the fields there and javascript would then just "select" the values from the fields. I would really appreciate this help @Guillermo Siliceo Trueba.

Comment: It seems you already tried the custom field way, where are you stuck? Could you share your custom field code?

Comment: Tried this but it does not appear on the edit section             ```$('#academy.id').parent().hide()
  academies = $('#academy.id').html()
  $('#company_profiles.company_id').change ->
    companies = $('#company_profiles.company_id :selected').text()
    escaped_companies = companies.replace(/([ #;&,.+*~\':"!^$[\]()=>|\/@])/g, '\\$1')
    options = $(academies).filter("optgroup[label='#{companies}']").html()
    if options
      $('#academy.id').html(options)
      $('#academy.id').parent().show()
    else
      $('#academy.id').empty()
      $('#academy.id').parent().hide()```

Comment: I moved your comment to the question itself, you can edit it to add additional information.
Where did you put that code, in which file?

Comment: Hey Guillermo, so I added this in a file in /custom path, same path as ui.js and added in ui.js a /=require tree. At first, I wasn't even able to get the necessary data from the models (there is a big chain, lot of has_many belnogs_to between) but I solved that getting it directly from the database using SQL on the rails_admin initializer, but I cant connect the JavaScript. Thnx for all the help my friend!

Comment: I updated the question with a suggestion to where to put your js